# $L(w)=\langle v,w\rangle$ a type of functional?

Tags: linear-algebra

> **Theorem**: Let V be a finite dimensional vector space over $K$, with a non-degenerate scalar product. Given a functional $L:V\to K$ there exists a unique element $v\in V$ such that: $L(w)=\langle v,w\rangle$
>
> for all $w\in V$.
>
> **Proof**. Consider the set of all functionals on $V$ which are of type $L_v$, for some $v\in V$. This set is a subspace of $V*$, because of the zero functional is of this type, and we have the formulas
>
> $L_{v_1}+L_{v_2}=L_{v_1+v_2}\:\:\:\:\:\text{and}\:\:\:\:\:L_{cv}=cL_{v}$
>
> Furthemore, if $\{v_1,...,v_n\}$ is a basis of $V$, then $L_{v_1},...L_{v_n}$ are linearly independent. Proof: If $x_1,...,x_n\in K$ are such that:
>
> $x_1L_{v_1}+...+x_nL_{v_n}=0\\L_{x_1v_1}+...+L_{x_n v_n}=0$
>
> and hence
>
> $L_{x_1v_1+...+x_n v_n}=0$
>
> However, if $v\in V$, and $L_v=0$, then $v=0$ by the definition of non-degeneracy. Hence:
>
> $x_1v_1+...+x_n v_n=0$,
>
> and therefore $x_1=...=x_n=0$, thereby proving our assertion. We conclude that the space of functionals of type $L_v\:(v\in V)$ is a subspace of $V*$, of the same dimension as $V*$, whence equal to $V*$. This proves the theorem.$\blacksquare$ Book: *"Linear Algebra" by Serge Lang*

**Questions**:

**1)** How do I read $L(w)=\langle v,w\rangle$?

**2)** How can $w$ and $v$ belong to $V$ if a functional is $upvarphi:V\to K$ and K is the field of scalars that does not belong to $V$? Where is the $c\in K$?

**3)** What does it mean "Given a functional $L:V\to K$ there exists a unique element $v\in V$ such that: $L(w)=\langle v,w\rangle$"? Is a different functional by element of $V$ or is $w$ fixed for all elements of $V$?

**4)** On the last paragraph it is stated "We conclude that the space of **functionals of type $L_v\:(v\in V)$** is a subspace of $V*$". What are functionals of type $L_v\:(v\in V)$?

I am sorry for the length. I am self-studying and I have been stuck on this theorem for a while. Any incoherence in the code feel free to comment or edit.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Let $V$ be a finite-dimensional vector space, let $F$ be its field of scalars, and suppose you've equipped $V$ with an inner product $\langle\cdot\rangle$.
2. The inner product $\langle \cdot \rangle$ is a function which takes in two vectors and produces a scalar: $\langle\cdot\rangle: V\times V \rightarrow F$. (Sometimes, it's convenient to think of an inner product as measuring the similarity between two vectors.) The inner product has various additional properties such as being linear in both of its arguments. For clarity, I'll use the unusual notation $L(v,w)$ for the inner product to make it clear that it's a function.
3. A *functional* is a linear mapping from vectors $V$ to scalars $F$.
4. If you fix a vector $v$, the function $L(v, \underline{\hspace{1em}})$ is a function which takes in a vector $w\in V$ and outputs a scalar $L(v,w)\in F$.  Because the inner product is linear in both arguments, the function $L(v,\underline{\hspace{1em}})$ is moreover a *functional*.  (Note that your book uses the notation $L_v$ to refer to the map $L(v,\underline{\hspace{1em}})$)
5. The question you might ask is "Of all the functionals $V\rightarrow F$ that exist, how many of them can be written in the form $L(v,\underline{\hspace{1em}})$ for some choice of $v$?  What functionals can't be written this way?"  The surprising answer is—*all* linear functionals can be written in the form $L(v, \underline{\hspace{1em}})$ for appropriate choice of $v\in V$. That's what the theorem is proving.

The proof of the theorem is like this:

1. Let $V^*$ denote the set of all functionals $V\rightarrow F$. The set of all functionals $V^*$ is a *vector space* just like $V$ because you can add any two functionals together to get a new functional: $(f+g)(v) = f(v) + g(v)$ and you can multiply any functional by a scalar to get a new functional $(\alpha f)(v) = \alpha\times f(v)$.
2. We know that for any vector $v$, the function $L(v, \underline{\hspace{1em}})$   is a linear functional—it belongs to the set $V^*$. Let's consider the set of all functions that can be written in the form $L(v,\underline{\hspace{1em}})$ for some $v\in V$. Call the set of functions $W \equiv \{ L(v, \underline{\hspace{1em}})\;:\:v\in V\}.$
3. What we're trying to prove is that $W = V^*$. We'll prove it by showing that $W$ is a vector space, that $W \subseteq V^*$ and that $W$ has the same dimension as $V^*$, which is enough to show that they're equal.
4. $W$ is a vector space. If you have a scalar $\alpha \in F$ and a function of the form $L(v,\underline{\hspace{1em}})$, it follows that $\alpha \times L(v,\underline{\hspace{1em}}) = L(\alpha v,\underline{\hspace{1em}})$ because the inner product is linear. So the scalar multiple of a function that belongs to $W$ is another function that belongs to $W$.  For the same reason, you can show that the sum of two functions that belong to $W$ is another function that belongs to $W$: $L(u,\underline{\hspace{1em}}) + L(v,\underline{\hspace{1em}}) = L(u+v,\underline{\hspace{1em}}).$ This proves that $W$ is a vector space.
5. As we've established already, every function in $W$ is a functional $V\rightarrow F$. $V^*$ is the set of all functionals. So obviously $W\subseteq V^*$.
6. How do we show that $W$ has the same dimension as $V^*$?  Well, we already know (or can show) that $V^*$ has the same dimension as $V$. So we'll show that $V$ and $W$ have the same dimension. We'll show that if there are $n$ linearly-independent vectors in $V$, then there are correspondingly $n$ linearly-independent vectors in $W$.

   Suppose there are $n$ linearly-independent vectors $v_1\ldots v_n$ in $V$. This means that the weighted sum $\sum_i \alpha_i v_i$ is zero only when all of the coefficients $\alpha_i$ are zero. Consider the corresponding linear functionals in $W$:  $L(v_1,\underline{\hspace{1em}})\ldots L(v_n, \underline{\hspace{1em}}).$ Can we show that these functionals are linearly independent, too?

   We can. Recall that one property of the inner product is that it must be nondegenerate: $L(v,w) = 0$ only when $v=0$ or $w=0$.   If we have a weighted sum of our functionals $\sum_i \alpha_i L(v_i, \underline{\hspace{1em}})$, we can rewrite it (using the rules for multiplying and adding functionals) as one giant functional $$L\left(\sum_i \alpha_i v_i, \; \underline{\hspace{1em}}\right).$$ Because the inner product is non-degenerate, the giant functional will only be the zero functional when that weighted sum $\sum_i \alpha_i v_i$ is zero. But because the $v_i$ are linearly independent, that weighted sum will only be zero when all the constants are zero. Hence the weighted sum of $\sum_i \alpha_i L(v_i, \cdot)$ is zero only when all of the constants are zero. Hence the $L(v_i, \cdot)$ are $n$ linearly-independent members of $W$. Hence $W$ has dimension $n$, just like $V$ and $V^*$. Hence $W=V^*$.
7. Hence $W = V^*$ and so every linear functional can be written in the form $L(v,\underline{\hspace{1em}})$ for an appropriate choice of $v$.

Comment: Inner product is _not_ linear in both of its arguments when $F = \mathbb C$.

Comment: So linear functionals is all about inner products? What about the integral over $\mathscr{C}(-\infty,\infty)$ the space of all continuous functions? I am aware the integral itself cannot be seen as an inner product such as $\int_\limits{0}^{1} f d\mu$ unless the function multiplies by another function like $\int_\limits{0}^{1} f.g d\mu$ right? Thanks for your answer!

Comment: @Pedro, notice that $V$ is _finite dimensional_ in the statement. For infinite dimensional spaces, there is a [variant of the theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riesz_representation_theorem) in case of [Hilbert spaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_space).

Comment: So instead consider the space $\mathscr{C}_[0,1]$ of all continuous functions on the interval [0,1]. Could you now answer my questions?

Comment: So, $L_{v_1}$ is a functional and $L_{v_2}$ is another, right?

Comment: @Pedro Yes, that's right. One sends $w \mapsto \langle v_1, w\rangle$. The other sends $w \mapsto \langle v_2, w\rangle$. They both send $V\rightarrow F$.

Answer (score 1):

This is what is known as the Riesz-Representation theorem for Finite dimensional vector spaces.
For a fixed $v\in V$
$$L_{v}:V \to K$$

defines as follows. for a $w \in V$, $$L_{v}(w)=\langle w,v \rangle $$. You have to check that this a linear transformation.

Now what this theorem asserts that any linear functional is of this type. So for each $v \in V$, there will correspond a linear function $L_{v}$. Now what it shows is that any Linear functional on $V$, is of this type.

In other words if $T:V\to K$, is a linear functional, then what you have to prove is that there exists a unique $v \in V$ such that $T=L_{v}$.

The book has done the proof in an indirect way. It has taken this collection say $L=\{\ L_{v} | v\in V \}\ $ which is a subset of $V^{*}$, which is the set of all linear functionals. Then he has proved that this subset $L$ is a subspace of $V^{*}$, whose dimension is same as $V^{*}$, and hence $L=V^{*}$, and you get your desired result.

Answer (score 1):

> 1) How do I read $L(w)=⟨v,w⟩$?

Fix any $v\in V$. Then you can define function $L_v\colon V\to K$ with formula $L_v(w) = \langle v, w\rangle ,\ \forall w\in V$.

> 2) How can $w$ and $v$ belong to $V$ if a functional is
>   $\varphi\colon V\to K$ and $K$ is the field of scalars that does not
>   belong to $V$? Where is the $c\in K$?

If $v,w$ are in $V$, then by definition $\langle v,w\rangle\in K$. Hence, the map $w\mapsto \langle v,w\rangle$ has domain $V$ and codomain $K$, as required for a map to be functional.

> 3) What does it mean "Given a functional $L\colon V\to K$ there exists a unique
>   element $v\in V$ such that: $L(w)=⟨v,w⟩$"? Is a different functional by
>   element of $V$ or is $w$ fixed for all elements of $V$?

It means that there is a function $\Phi\colon V^*\to V$ such that for any functional $\varphi$ the following is true: $$\varphi(w) = \langle \Phi(\varphi), w\rangle,\ \forall w\in V$$ This is a bit messy way to write it, so we could define $v_\varphi:=\Phi(\varphi)\in V$ and write $$\varphi(w) = \langle v_\varphi,w\rangle.$$

It is important to notice that $v_\varphi$ depends on $\varphi$ and that $w$ is just an argument of the functional. Also, notice that $\Phi$ wouldn't be well-defined function if $v_\varphi$ weren't unique vector in $V$ with the given property.

> 4) On the last paragraph it is stated "We conclude that the space of
>   functionals of type $L_v\ (v\in V)$ is a subspace of $V^∗$". What are functionals of type $L_v\ (v\in V)$?

Functional $\varphi$ is of type $L_v$, for a fixed $v\in V$, if $\varphi = L_v$ and $L_v$ is defined as above.

Hopefully, this will make it clear to you what is going on.

However, are you sure that $L_v$ is defined the way you wrote it and not $L_v(w) = \langle w,v\rangle$? There is important difference in case $K=\mathbb C$ since scalar product is sesquilinear (i.e antilinear in second argument) and $L_v$ defined the way you wrote wouldn't be linear, but antilinear functional. Unless the author follows different convention.

Comment: The book does not necessarily defienes if $\langle v,w\rangle$ is an inner product. Is it an inner product or functional notation like $\langle \varphi,v_i\rangle$? Thanks for your answer!

Comment: @Pedro, the first argument is element of $V$, so it is kind of bilinear/sesquilinear form.

Comment: So, $L_{v_1}$ is a functional and $L_{v_2}$ is another, right?